# Flutter mapping from sqlite to List

Tags: flutter

im trying to map an entry from sql to a List with a different structure. the SQL entry will be created like this:

```
await db.execute(
    'CREATE TABLE $tableTodo($todoColumnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, '
        '                    $todoColumnTodoName TEXT, '
        '                    $todoColumnJob TEXT, '
        '                    $todoColumnPriority TEXT, '
        '                    $todoColumnTeamId INTEGER, '
        '                    $todoColumnTeam TEXT, '
        '                    $todoColumnNote TEXT, '
        '                    $todoColumnStartingDate INTEGER,'
        '                    $todoColumnEndingDate INTEGER)');
```

my class for this list is build like this:

```
class TodoInCharts {
  int id;
  String name;
  DateTime startTime;
  DateTime endTime;
  List<int> participants;

  TodoInCharts({this.id, this.name, this.startTime, this.endTime, this.participants});

  TodoInCharts.map(dynamic obj) {
    this.id = obj['id'];
    this.name = obj['todoName'];
    this.startTime = obj['startingDate'];
    this.endTime = obj['endingDate'];
    this.participants = obj['teamId'];
 }

  TodoInCharts.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    this.id = map['id'];
    this.name = map['todoName'];
    this.startTime = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(map['startingDate'] * 1000);
    this.endTime = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(map['endingDate'] * 1000);
    this.participants = map['teamId'];
  }
 }
```

Im not quite sure about the mapping here, because in SQL i have always one teamId, but for this special list i have to convert it into List of int. I guess the "fromMap" is something missing, but i cant figure out what its needed to make a correct List here.

Example:

```
var Todo = [
  TodoInCharts(id: 3, name: 'todo01', startTime: DateTime(2020, 5, 1), endTime: DateTime(2020, 9, 1), participants: [1])]
```

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your question.  Are you trying to convert `'teamId'` to a list, or trying to fetch the number of participants in the team?

Comment: I want to convert teamId into a list..so its not a list of {id,name,starttime, endtime, teamid} ...it should be {id,name,starttime, endtime,[teamid]}

Comment: maybe i can alter my mapping?

Comment: like so `this.participants = [map['teamId']];` ?